# If I export my database with phpmyadmin will it lock my tables or take my database down?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to create a backup of my database using the phpmyadmin export function. the database can't have any down time so I need to know if running a database export will take the database down?

I've looked on-line but all I get is instructions on how to export. No one tells you if it will be down whilst it does its task. I just need a strait answer so I can Export or organise a safe down time to export.

Any help is really appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, tables won't be locked, database won't be down. But, if your database is large and it takes long time to backup it, you can sometimes expect performance degradation(slow SQL queries from your application).

Answer (score 2):

I have read about people having problem with innoDB tables where it makes a READ LOCK.

If your application is mostly read I would make a service windows where there might be downtime (better safe than sorry).

[Source](http://forum.teamspeak.com/showthread.php/59821-All-clients-disconnect-on-MySQL-export-with-phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the input, I'll probably schedule in some down time.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a large database (ie. three digits of MBs or more), you probably shouldn't be doing this with PHPMyAdmin or via your browser. Better use `mysqldump` on command line instead:

```
# mysqldump -u UserName -p PassWord your_db > your_db.sql
```

...and if the database size is < 100 MB, you probably needn't be too concerned over MySQL performance on your site; unless your server is very slow or under constant heavy loads.